# Adding a value to variable nested too deeply

Tags: bash

I wanna GET request with variable x in command like this

```
curl 'abc.com' --data '{"songs":{"module":"server","method":"get_songs","param":{"songid":$x}}}'
```

but the command can't get the value of x, because it's nested too deeply!

Hope you help!

Comment: Nesting doesn't matter, it's just a string.  You just need to escape it from the single quotes and join it back.

Comment: this is what I mean: try  `x=4; echo 'the value '"$x"' set to x'`

Answer (score 1):

single quotes is hiding the variable from `bash`, the nesting doesn't matter, it's just a string.

you can escape the variable form single quotes, let `bash` substitute the value and then join back to the rest of the string.

```
... '{"songs":{"module":"server","method":"get_songs","param":{"songid":'"$x"'}}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `$x` is not replaced because it is embedded in a string enclosed in apostrophes. The variables are not expanded and the escape sequences do not work in the strings enclosed in apostrophes.

There are multiple solutions for your problem.

The simplest one is to close the string before the variable and use another string after it:

```sh
curl 'abc.com' \
  --data '{"songs":{"module":"server","method":"get_songs","param":{"songid":'$x'}}}'
```

However, this produces unexpected results if the value of `$x` contains spaces or characters that are special to the shell (like `*` etc).

It has a very simple fix: let the variable `$x` be outside the strings enclosed in apostrophes but enclose it in quotes:

```sh
curl 'abc.com' \
  --data '{"songs":{"module":"server","method":"get_songs","param":{"songid":'"$x"'}}}'
```

---

However, while this works, it is not easy to read and the quotes around `$x` can be confused with the quotes from the JSON.

I recommend to use the here-doc syntax to build the JSON:

```sh
DATA=$(cat << END
{"songs":{"module":"server","method":"get_songs","param":{"songid":$x}}}
END
)

curl 'abc.com' --data "$DATA"
```

This way the variable is expanded and there is no need for extra quotes or apostrophes.

---

This approach (and also your initial approach) has a major drawback. You need to write the JSON manually and a missing or an extra comma or quote will break it. A simple way to prevent this is to use a tool (for example [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)) to generate the JSON:

```sh
DATA=$(echo -n "$x" | jq -s -R '
{
  songs: {
    module: "server",
    method: "get_songs",
    param: { songid: . }
  }
}
')

curl 'abc.com' --data "$DATA"
```

The advantage of using `jq` (or other tool designed to work with JSON) becomes visible when `$x` contains characters that must be encoded when used in JSON (quotes, newlines). The variable substitution provided by the shell does not do any encoding for them, the resulting JSON is malformed and the server where you send it will reject your request.

Comment: `\'` isn't an escape within single quotes in Bash, it's just a literal backslash and an ending quote. Also it's not shell operators like `;` and `>` that are a problem in unquoted expansions, but glob characters like `*`.